# Displaying "info" by selecting foreign key in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I was introduced to Python and Django about two weeks ago, so bear with me. I should also say now that I am using Django 1.6 and Python 3.3.

My project is an order management system. Here's how it works: A customer comes into a store and orders an item. That item is put in an order, which is idle until the employee places the order with a supplier. Basically, I have an Order table, which collects information like customer_name, order_date, status, etc. Then I have an EmployeeOrder table (1-1 relationship with Order) which has all of the elements of an Order, but also takes in employee_placed and employee_order_date (pretty much just extends Order).

What I'm trying to do is write code so that when the user selects which customer Order is being fulfilled by placing an EmployeeOrder, that customer Order's information is displayed. I don't really care how it is displayed right now, a pop up will work just fine. I just don't know how to do it and I haven't come across it anywhere. Right now the drop down box just displays Order 1, Order 2, etc. The user isn't going to remember which items were included in which order, so that's why I want the order information to be shown. Anyway, here's my code so far:

models.py

```
    class Order(models.Model):
       customer_order_date = models.DateTimeField('Date helped')
       customer_placed = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
       employee_helped = models.ForeignKey(Employee)

       STATUS_OF_ORDER = (
          ('IDLE', 'Not yet ordered'),
          ('SHIP', 'Awaiting delivery'),
          ('PICK', 'Ready for pickup'),
          ('UNAV', 'Unavailable for order'),
          ('BACK', 'Backordered - awaiting delivery'),
          ('CANC', 'Canceled by customer'),
          ('ARCH', 'Fulfilled - archived'),

       )

       status = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=STATUS_OF_ORDER,
                                 default='IDLE', editable=False)
       paid = models.BooleanField('Paid', default=False)
       ship = models.BooleanField('Ship', default=False)
       comments = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
       item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

       def __str__(self):
          return 'Order ' + str(self.id)

       def is_idle(self):
          return self.status == 'IDLE'

    class EmployeeOrder(models.Model):
       order = models.OneToOneField(Order, primary_key=True,
                                    limit_choices_to={'status': 'IDLE'})
       employee_order_date = models.DateTimeField('Date ordered')
       employee_placed = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

admin.py

```
    class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('customer_order_date', 'customer_placed')
       raw_id_fields = ('customer_placed', 'item')    

    class EmployeeOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('employee_order_date', 'employee_placed')
```

Any and all help is appreciated as I still admit that I am a total noob when it comes to Python and Django!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want an employee to be able to use the admin site to create an employee order from a customer order. I think it could be as simple as adding a raw ID field for the customer order. That is, I think you can just change EmployeeOrderAdmin like so:

```
class EmployeeOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('employee_order_date', 'employee_placed')
    raw_id_fields = ('order',)
```

Now when an employee creates an employee order, they will be able to use the OrderAdmin page to find the order they want.

Additionally, suppose you want that pop-up window to display the orders in a particular way. In that case, keep in mind that requests to display that pop-up window will contain an additional GET parameter called `pop`. You could:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ActiveOfferAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.GET.get('pop'):
            return qs.order_by(...)
        return qs
```

Comment: You know what..that works great! I was way over-thinking it! I guess I just figured since there weren't many orders that would be chosen from (at least in theory), a drop-down box would be fine. Unfortunately you can't see any data from the order when using the drop-down. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! That is how I would do it. I believe the drop-down box will show whatever is returned by your object's \_\_str__ or \_\_unicode__ method, but I generally try to avoid using those methods for anything other than debugging.

Comment: You are correct in thinking that. Like I said, it's not very descriptive. This way is much better. Now I just need to work on my join tables so that the item names show up in the order.

Comment: I think I know what you are getting at. I added a tip about it to my answer.